# Find elements in an UIWebView

Tags: ios, ui-automation, earlgrey

I want to write an UI automation test that log in by using Google. The webview is embedded in the app. In Earlgrey, how can I select a text field or a button of a web view. 
Thanks

Comment: If your webview is embedded in the app then each element that you need to select should have an accessibility wrapper around it. You should be able to interact with elements using that and run regular EarlGrey statements. Is there a specific hierarchy or case that you would like to handle?

Comment: No specific hierarchy at all. For instance, I just want to touch down `Allow` button. Tried to use matcher `grey_buttonTitle(@"Allow")` but it can't find the button. I doubt that EarlGrey can select an element inside an UIWebview

Comment: Note that `grey_buttonTitle` only selects UIButton classes, `grey_text(@"Allow")` is a better alternative here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried `grey_text` but it still can't find the element.

Comment: does grey_accessibilityLabel(@"Allow") or grey_accessibilityID(@"Allow) work? And on a separate note, is it a WKWebView or a UIWebView?

Comment: @sahara108, any update on this issue?

Comment: I still haven't found any solution. Do you have answer?

Answer (score 1):

EarlGrey provides a great log of the UI hierarchy when a test fails. My suggestion is to write a test that navigates to the login view, and then force EarlGrey to fail. Then in the log, look for the elements you need. You should see something like:

```
--<WebAccessibilityObjectWrapper:0x7fbca2422fb0; AX=Y; AX.value='Email'; AX.frame={{72, 145}, {270, 38}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 164}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='Y'>
--<WebAccessibilityObjectWrapper:0x7fbca4e82360; AX=Y; AX.value='Password'; AX.frame={{72, 201}, {270, 38}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 220}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitNone'; AX.focused='N'>
```

From this log you can see that the two elements are accessible via:

```
EarlGrey().selectElementWithMatcher(grey_accessibilityValue("Email"))
EarlGrey().selectElementWithMatcher(grey_accessibilityValue("Password"))
```

Comment: Or you can even put a break point and punch this into gdb: 
`po [GREYElementHierarchy hierarchyStringForElement:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow]`